# Join two tables and group properly the results

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I'm using a SQL Database to store some people counting results from video analysis.
The **counting** table can be summarized like this :

```
rowid (auto increment int)  |     created_at (date)   |   type (int)  | count_value (int)
----------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+-------------
```

Later, I wanted to add some attributes for the people detected, still using image procesing.
I could have altered the **counting** table, but for every now attribute added I would had to manually alter the **counting** table. I wanted a dynamic solution.
A second table was created, called **attributes**, which is quite simple.

```
rowid (auto increment int)  |     key (string)   |   value (string)  | row_id_counting (int)
----------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------
```

For example, if my algorithm detect 30yo Male person, the following rows will appear in the **counting** and **attributes** tables :

```
COUNTING :

rowid |     created_at    | type | count_value 
------+-------------------+------+-------------
 150  | 2019.10.18  08:50 |  1   |      1


ATTRIBUTES :

rowid  |     key   |   value  | row_id_counting
-------+-----------+----------+---------------
  120  | "gender"  |  "M"     |      150 
  121  |  "age"    |  "30"    |      150
```

If someday my **counting** table have to store other type of datas (for example cats or vehicle), I can specify it under the `type` column, and I won't have to store useless attributes for these datas since the attributes are stored in another table, and created dynamically.

I can also easily retrieve some datas from **counting** with specific attributes using JOIN in my SQL requests.

---

Now, I want to sum all the datas with the same attributes per hour, in order to create some statistics from my 'counting' table. My first solution is :

```
SELECT SUM(count_value), attr.key, attr.value, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00',created_at, 'localtime') as timestr 
    FROM counting cnt 
    LEFT JOIN attributes attr ON cnt.rowid = attr.row_id_counting
    WHERE datetime(created_at,'localtime') BETWEEN '2019-10-16 22:00:0.000000' AND '2019-10-17 22:00:00.000000' 
    AND cnt.type = 1
    GROUP BY timestr,attr.key, attr.value
```

The results looked promising at first, this request returning even a value for the counting rows with no attributes.
But a simple set of data can easily show the limitations :

- One 50yo person, unknown gender
- One 20yo male
- One female, unknown age
- One person, unknown age and gender

**Results :**

```
 SUM(count_value)   key       value       timestr
 1                  (null)    (null)      2019-10-18 10:00:00
 1                  age       20          2019-10-18 10:00:00
 1                  age       50          2019-10-18 10:00:00
 1                  gender    F           2019-10-18 10:00:00
 1                  gender    M           2019-10-18 10:00:00
```

Even if I add the (null) (null) row to the sums of the age attributes or gender attributes, I only count 3 people instead of 4. The missing person for the age sum is the female with unknown age and the missing one for the gender sum is the 50yo persons with unknown gender.

Is there any way to alter this SQL request in order to have the following rows instead :

```
 SUM(count_value)   key       value       timestr
 2                  age       (null)      2019-10-18 10:00:00
 1                  age       20          2019-10-18 10:00:00
 1                  age       50          2019-10-18 10:00:00
 2                  gender    (null)      2019-10-18 10:00:00
 1                  gender    F           2019-10-18 10:00:00
 1                  gender    M           2019-10-18 10:00:00
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted sample data in text form or a fiddle for your expected results.

Comment: This is one of the problems with Entity-Attribute-Value table designs. It will get even harder when you have to answer questions like "find all _people_ seen between two dates where the gender was female, and the age was between 30 and 45, and the hair colour was either brown or black"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I ended using two SQL requests.
The first one retrieve the list of possible attributes from the attributes

```
SELECT key FROM attributes GROUP BY key
```

**Results:**

```
age
gender
```

Then I can create dynamically the second request. If have more attributes added in the future, this request will grow in size :

```
SELECT SUM(count_value), a0.value, a1.value FROM counting cet 
    LEFT JOIN attributes a0 ON cnt.rowid = a0.row_id_counting AND a0.key = 'age' 
    LEFT JOIN attributes a1 ON cnt.rowid = a1.row_id_counting AND a1.key = 'gender' 
    WHERE datetime(created_at,'localtime') BETWEEN '2019-10-17 23:00:00.000000' AND '2019-10-18 23:00:00.000000’ AND cnt.type = 1 
    GROUP BY c0.value, c1.value
```

**Results:**

```
 SUM(count_value)   key       value       timestr
 1                  (null)    (null)      2019-10-18 10:00:00
 1                  age       20          2019-10-18 10:00:00
 1                  age       50          2019-10-18 10:00:00
 1                  gender    F           2019-10-18 10:00:00
 1                  gender    M           2019-10-18 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is this: how is the DB supposed to know that type 1 is a person and you're expecting gender and age for them, and type 2 is a cat and you expect the tail color?

if you know that, you can try to build a query that would take it into account, ie.

```
select type, name, (select color from <the other table> where <the attributes match>),
from first table where <conditions>
```

But I'm afraid that's pretty much your only option

Comment: The `type` column is known and I forgot to add the clause "WHERE type = 1" in my question, thanks for pointing it out, I edited my question. In fact this attribute is pretty much useless in this issue, I just added it in order to explain why my database was designed in this way.

Comment: But your idea is nice, maybe I should add a`type`column in the `attributes` table. Then first is list all my possible key from the attributes for a selected type, and use it to create my second request. I'll try it !

Comment: or you can add a third table that would explain which attributes you expect for each type and join through it - in that case you can inner join from main table to dictionary one and then outer join over to the additional attributes and it would solve your problem